# How to create an array of templates

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template

I need to create a timeline. For this I need cards repeating.

I already created and manage to show the template of the card I want.

But now I need to make this repeat... I do not have a BD right now, so first I'm creating the frontend of the application, so for now I only need to create a simple array that will repeat my template x times.

This is my HTML:

```
  <ion-list>
    <enviouTemplate [cardEnviou]="enviouCard" *ngIf="buttonClicked1"></enviouTemplate>
    <recebeuTemplate [cardRecebeu]="recebeuCard" *ngIf="buttonClicked2"></recebeuTemplate>
  </ion-list>
```

The father TS don't have any code right now, this is working purely by using the children TS directly to HTML.

How can I make the cards repeat?

The ngIf is there because there'll be two kind of cards, so don't mind that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried the `*ngFor`?

Comment: Put *ngfor with ng-content as the parent element

Comment: But I don't understand how is the sintax for the array in the parent TS

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work, right now its like this:

HTML:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <enviouTemplate  [cardEnviou]="card" *ngIf="buttonClicked1"></enviouTemplate>
    <recebeuTemplate [cardRecebeu]="card" *ngIf="buttonClicked2"></recebeuTemplate>
</ion-list>
```

Parent TS(only for test):

```
cards : any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

But my question now is about something that I read, that its not a good practice to use ngFor inside ion-list.

So how should I build the html?

One thing to point, I need to use the ngIf, because I have two timelines that will show up only when a button is selected, and I see that the application don't accept ngFor and ngIf in the same element...